How to use JPA @Query with a native SQL query to get random results in Spring Data JPA?
I'm developing a Spring Boot application with Spring Data JPA, and I need to implement a repository method that fetches a random selection of questions from a Question table, filtered by a specific category. I tried using the @Query annotation but encountered an issue.
here is the code:
package com.example.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.model.Question;

@Repository
public interface QuestionDao extends JpaRepository<Question, Integer> {

    List<Question> findByCategory(String category);

    @Query(value = "SELECT q.id FROM question q Where q.category=:category ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT :numQ", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Integer> findRandomQuestionsByCategory(String category, int numQ);
}


error:  MySQL: no viable alternative at input 'SELECT * FROM Question
q WHERE q.category = :category ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT :'

What I’ve Tried:
Initially, I used ORDER BY RANDOM(), but I switched to ORDER BY RAND() for MySQL compatibility.
What I'm Expecting:
I want a working JPA repository method that retrieves a specified number of random questions from the "Question" table, based on the provided category.

You can't bind a placeholder to the LIMIT clause as you are doing.  What you can do is to provide an implementation to the findRandomQuestionsByCategory() method and use the JPA repo methods to enforce a limit to the size of the result set.
@Override
public List<Integer> findRandomQuestionsByCategory(String category, int limit) {
    String sql = "SELECT q.id FROM question q WHERE q.category = :category ORDER BY RAND()";
    return entityManager.createQuery(sql, Integer.class)
                        .setParameter("category", category)
                        .setMaxResults(limit)
                        .getResultList();
}


This error  is for an issue in your query. Specifically, when using native queries with Spring Data JPA, placeholders like : for parameters need to be used carefully, especially with the LIMIT clause,and the point is that MySQL expects a numeric value directly in the LIMIT clause, and using : as a parameter placeholder won't work there. I think you can't directly bind the LIMIT clause using :limit in a native query.
The solution I can suggest is using pagination to limit result record count.
public interface QuestionRepository extends JpaRepository<Question, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Question WHERE category = :category ORDER BY RAND()", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Question> findRandomQuestionsByCategory(@Param("category") String category, Pageable pageable);
}

In my solution, you can pass a PageRequest to limit the number of results in your service:
int questionCount = 5;  
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, questionCount);  

List<Question> randomQuestions = questionRepository.findRandomQuestionsByCategory("some_category", pageable);

Please leave a comment if there is a problem

This solution worked. I did not know about pagable. It helped, Thank you so much!

I am so happy to see that!  So please accept my answer to guide other users with same problem

test this:
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
@Query(value = "SELECT q.id FROM question q Where q.category=:category ORDER BY radiant LIMIT :numQ")
    List<Integer> findRandomQuestionsByCategory(@Param("category")String category,@Param("numQ") int numQ);


Binding in the Limit clause isn't allowed, so this won't work. Adding @Param won't help here.

@M.Deinum when we do set nativeQuery = true you are correct but I did remove that and I am using this way of code in my project and it is working correctly.
